# How to create a table programmatically with making it open for update using checkbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer. I need to develop a table that combine the data of four tables in the database. The schema of each table:
Employee Table: Username, Name, Job, DivisonCode
Division Table: DivisionCode, DivisionName
Course Table: CourseID, CourseName, GroupID
Group Table: GroupID, GroupName
Employee_Course Table: Username, CourseID
(The first key in each table is the primary key)

I already developed this table using GridView, but I faced many problems in making it open for updates since I inserted checkboxes in the cells under the Courses to update the record for each employee very fast and in one place. I need now to develop this table programmatically and since I have three groups or types of courses I will need to three tables like the above one. Besides that, each table has different number of rows and cells since the Group #2 consists of 7 courses and Group #3 consists of 9 courses.

Therefore, how to develop this kind of tables programmatically?

Comment: So what have you tried so far?Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to write your update logic in Checkbox Check event.
Because i have also same problem in ago and i do this and that will work.
So try to write your logic in Checkbox's event.
If You get problem then add your code and i will help you...